# On clicking the back button Activity is restarting itself

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am starting an activity using intent like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("datacover",arrayList);
Intent intent = new Intent(TroubleShootActivity.this,SearchResultsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("bundle",bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Im not finishing the activity, but still when i click on back button in the next activity it does not return to the previous activity instead restarts itself.

Code for the other activity:

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements InnerDetailsFragment.OntroubleshootinneritemsListener,InnerDetailsFragment.OnHandleBack,CompleteDetailsFragment.OnHandleBack {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
    if(!getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.twoPaneMode)){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }else{
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }

    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment Inner = new InnerDetailsFragment();
    bundle.putString("val", "search");
    Inner.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_search_results,Inner);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();


}

@Override
public void onBackClick(String inner) {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void ontroubleinneritemelected(int position, String heading, CoverageData coverageData) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("coverage",coverageData);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment Detailsf= new CompleteDetailsFragment();
    Detailsf.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_search_results,Detailsf);
    ft.addToBackStack("completedetails");
    ft.commit();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

Comment: use finish() instead of super.onBackPressed();

Comment: Could you share InnerDetailsFragment?  Or these 3 listeners.

Comment: Dont override the back button at all. not sure what you are gaining from it

Comment: @JaydeepPatel  
 
there are two fragments if im on second fragment back should come to first fragment , if i add finish(); it will directly go out of the activity from second fragment.

Comment: @Doomsknight i removed the onBackpressed() override, i got the same result.

Comment: DId you also remove `onBackClick()`? If so, its likely your other activity code is set to re-intialise / blank everything in `onResume()` methods etc.

Comment: no im not allowed to remove it, we need the back button on top of the screen which does the same thing as system back button..

Comment: also removed the fragment transaction so just loaded a blank screen in this activity and clicked system back button and it just re started the  same activity..weird..

Comment: Ah. Sorry i mis-read a few things. One last idea that comes to mind, is your back activity relaunching this activity again. Aka, it IS closing, going back to the previous, but is then Launching this activity again. Otherwise im out of ideas. It sounds like odd behaviour, but there will always be a reason/accidental mistake behind it.

Comment: oh man i have kept the  startActivity inside a for loop.. sorry for wasting all your time.

Comment: Lol. At least you found it. We all make mistakes ;) Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this in the second activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() { 
   finish();
}
```

fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_search_results,Detailsf);
    ft.commit();

Comment: there are two fragments if im on second fragment back should come to first fragment , if i add finish(); it will directly go out of the activity from second fragment.

Comment: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment Detailsf= new CompleteDetailsFragment();
    Detailsf.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_search_results,Detailsf);
    ft.addToBackStack("completedetails");
    ft.commit();

Comment: if you add fragment instead of replacing it, fragment manager let you keep the previous fragment and then by pressing back, you will go back to the previous fragmnet.

Comment: oh okay..let me try that

Comment: Just let me know the result of testing "add" instead of "replace".

Comment: sorry i have kept the startActivity inside a for loop.. dumb mistake.. and adding add and clicking back even when there is finish brings the first fragment back..

Answer (score -1):

Use below code...

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, PreviousActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```